# AngularJS Waiting for $resource Promise in the Scope of a User Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, window.open, ngresource

I'm pretty new to front end / AngularJS development and have read (but don't completely understand) a lot of stack overflow questions and other documentation about ng-resource / $resource and promises. I have kind of a weird situation.

I have this code in a submit function for when the user clicks a button to submit a form.

```
        var Resource = $resource("/urlHere",{},{save: {method:'POST', isArray:true}});
        Resource.save(JSON.stringify($scope.validQuery)).$promise.then(function(data) {

        $scope.initialResults=data;

        if($scope.initialResults.length === 0){
           alert("No Results Found!");

        }else if($scope.initialResults.length === 1){
            window.data = $scope.initialResults;
            window.open('/detailedResults');

       }else if($scope.initialResults.length > 1){
            window.data = $scope.initialResults;
            var popupWindowResults = window.open('/resultsGrid');
        }
      });
```

I need to open a certain tab depending on how many results I get. (Basically show a grid with multiple results to choose from or just show the single result if only 1 is returned) Using window.open works fine when it's not contained within the $promise.then. Within the $promise.then, the browsers are treating it as a pop-up and not a new tab as the result of the user clicking something.

Is there a way to just halt execution until the results are returned so that I can open a tab outside of the $promise.then and in the submit function? Any solution would be extremely helpful.

Comment: I am not sure why it happening but did you try to call a function that does the window.open ? And did you try with $window ( to inject) instead of the normal window ?

Comment: Yup I have tried both. What I THINK is going on here all has to do with the asynchronous call. The function that is executed, because of the USER clicking, finishes. Then the asynchronous call completes. The browser then doesn't think that the user is opening this tab and so it then treats it as an untrusted pop-up.

Comment: Perhaps you should consider a modal dialog instead of a new window. Usually results in a better user experience.

Comment: you could then simulate a click on a fictional <a> tag that would work like a get for a new page

Comment: @ClintPowell Thanks for your suggestion, however, the requirements are that the user wants to have a full fledge results page in a new tab, be able to keep it, and be able to go back to the search tab and get another results page.

Comment: Hmm. You can perhaps open the new window on the click method, have a "Loading results" screen on the window until the results load, then programmatically send the results to the child window.

Comment: @clint a good idea even if it may imply a lot of work just to open a tab. Furthermore it would imply that the page opened contains also an angular app, is it the case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/az066xcs/2/

```
$scope.getResults = function() {
    var win = window.open();

    // this is a placeholder for the async call that gets results
    setTimeout(function() {
        win.document.write('<h1>Results Loaded!</h1>');
    }, 1000);
};
```

You can open the window on click, then load results async and insert them into the new window. Obviously, a better solution than a blank window with `document.write` would be to have another angular app in the new window, or at least a simple javascript application.

Comment: This is the right idea, popup blockers allow new windows if the call is made from a stack that was initiated by a user-generated click event. Not if you call `window.open` on your own (which the OP does when trying to call `window.open` after the AJAX call

Comment: Ahhhh, yes this is great. Open the window on the user click and then update the window later when the results are returned. I basically am opening another angular app and I'm now using win.location.href='' to update the window when I get the results. Thanks a lot for your time!